# Angular 2 with app insights

Tags: angular, azure-application-insights

I am quite new to the Angular 2 world. I am trying to hook up angular 2 to microsoft app insights for performance  analytic. Does anyone have any luck in this area??Is it possible to determine if an angular component has rendered the dom fully?Hooking to life cycle events will require adding and implementing the code in every component

Comment: I created a package for it, with everything updated and working with the latest angular 4.x as well: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/angular-application-insights Available on npm `npm i -S @markpieszak/ng-application-insights`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Angular's [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) to achieve that:

```js
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor() {
        // DOM is not rendered yet
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // DOM is now rendered
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Just curious: Would I do this in the main component or in each child?

Comment: This method is called bottom-up, so first in the child components and then in the parent. So it depends on your needs :)

Comment: Interesting... so What do I actually put in the ngAfterViewInit()?  I tried copying the SDK initialization from azure, but since I'm using typescript, I'm getting all sorts of errors like `appInsights does not exist on type Window` and stuff